# How can i add a filter in Data window

Tags: sybase, powerbuilder, datawindow

I am very new in power builder. I am trying to add the filter in data window.
I have created a data window dw_trans which return the trans number & amount. I want to add the filter on the basis of trans number. user select the trans number only that specific row will show.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example

```
integer li_rc
long ll_rows, ll_filteredrows, ll_trans_id
string ls_filter, ls_original_filter

// in case you need original filter value
ls_original_filter = dw_trans.describe("Datawindow.Table.Filter") 

// create the filter as a string using the dw column name
// ll_trans_id set somewhere else in code (user input or whatever)
ls_filter = 'trans_no = ' + string(ll_trans_id)

//li_rc will be -1 if an error occurs
li_rc = dw_trans.setfilter(ls_filter)

//ll_rows will be number of rows left after filtering
ll_rows = dw_trans.filter()

// # of rows filtered out by current filter
ll_filteredrows = dw_trans.filteredcount()

// remove a filter
dw_trans.setfilter('')
dw_trans.filter()

//set back original filter
IF POS(ls_original_filter,'~"') > 0 THEN
// get rid of tilde doublequote since it is an invalid expression when we try to re-apply the filter
    ls_original_filter = replace(ls_original_filter,Pos(ls_original_filter,'~"') - 1, 2, "'")
// do twice since if there is one there will be two
    ls_original_filter = replace(ls_original_filter,Pos(ls_original_filter,'~"') - 1, 2, "'")
END IF
li_rc = dw_trans.setfilter(ls_original_filter)
ll_rows = dw_trans.filter()
```

Comment: Nice answer- I wouldn't be as generous am on the bench because of these questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have filter in two ways.
1st way.
Considering the the column values as a string and getting the input as a string, and finding the relative number or exact number.

2nd way.
you can have the numeric type filter. so that you can search the exact values. but cant search the relative values.

i will write the sample code for the both.

am considering your column name as cust_num. and having the SingleLineEdit control for Entering the input value. That name is sle_input. Write the following code on the button clicked event.code follows

### 1st way.

string ls_input
ls_input=sle_1.text
If len(trim(ls_imput)) =0 Then 
  Messagebox('Alert','Please Enter The value to filter')
  Return
End if 
dw_trans.setfilter("string(cust_num) like '"+string(ls_input)+"%'")
dw_trans.filter()

### 2nd Way.

string ls_input
ls_input=sle_1.text
If len(trim(ls_imput)) =0 Then 
  Messagebox('Alert','Please Enter The value to filter')
  Return
End if 
dw_trans.setfilter("cust_num = "+string(ls_input))
dw_trans.filter()

There are many awesome features in powerbuilder. its also possible to filter at the time of typing the numbers. Reply me if you want to know about that code.

Thanks
Raj~

Vote up if satisfy with this answer,else add comment for your specific requirements. So that others having the same question can find the answer quickly.

Comment: Thanks... Yes i want to know about that..
I have created a dropdowndatawindow which fetch the list of all the transaction. how can i get which trans is selected by user.

Comment: While creating the drop down datawindow you have choosed the data column and display column right. In the itemchanged event of that datawindow you can get the used selected data value. The code follows . write this code on itemchanged event of your datawindow.

Long ll_trans       
String ls_filter           
        
ll_trans = Long(data)      
        
If long(data) = 0 Then      
 ls_filter= ''        
Else      
 ls_filter = 'cust_num = '+data       
End If     
 
dw_trans.Setfilter(ls_filter)      
dw_trans.filter()

Comment: My purpose is create a drop down list & user select the trans number from the drop down list. & data will be show for that particular selected trans. So i have created the dropdowndatawindow which have the list of all the trans... but not able to get which tran number is selected from user. can i know your gmail id?

Comment: sorry for poor formatting in the comment section. use this code in your datawindow . So when the user select the option based on the values filter will be done.
This code will suit for you. To contact me visit this page and post your feedback. I think direct mail id are protected here . visit this [link](http://powerbuilder-india.blogspot.in/p/index.html). i will reply back.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easy.Try this on the `clicked()` event of your datawindow - it will filter all data into the datawindow from the selection.

```
integer li_colnbr, li_row
string ls_colname, ls_value, ls_filter, ls_type

if row = 0 then return //don't do nothing
ls_colname = dwo.name
li_row = row
li_colnbr = integer(this.describe(ls_colname + ".id")) //find the name of the column
    if li_colnbr = 0 then
        this.setredraw(true)
        return
    end if

ls_value = string(this.object.data[li_row, li_colnbr]) //get the value of the cell / item
    if isnull(ls_value) then
        ls_filter = "isnull(" + ls_colname + ")"
    else
        ls_type = lower(left(this.describe(ls_colname + ".coltype"), 5)) //get the type of the column
        choose case ls_type
            //creating the final filter
            case "decimal", "number", "long", "ulong", "real" //search into the help for all coltypes
                ls_filter = ls_colname + " = " + ls_value
            case else
                ls_filter = "string(" + ls_colname + ") = ~"" + ls_value + "~""
        end choose
    end if

this.setfilter(ls_filter) //setting the filter
this.filter()
this.sort() //done !
```

If you want to see again the original data retrieved just add this for example on `rbuttondown()` event:

```
this.setfilter('') //back to original filter
this.filter( )
this.sort( )
```